# Reading php://stderr

Tags: stderr

I want to read `php://stderr`. How can do it?

Do `php://stderr` and `STDERR` write to the same file? Because after writing to `php://stderr` I tried reading `STDERR` using `stream_get_contents` but I did not get any data?

Also while writing to `php://stderr` using `file_put_contents` do we need to use `APPEND` flag so that the data is not overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

> It is recommended that you simply use the constants STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR instead of manually opening streams using these wrappers.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 1):

You can't read from `php://stderr`.

Building on the answer of @user647772:

> It is recommended that you simply use the constants STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR instead of manually opening streams using these wrappers.
>
> ...
>
> `php://stdin` is read-only, whereas `php://stdout` and
> `php://stderr` are write-only.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Also since `php://stderr` essentially points to a stream using the APPEND is not needed because there is nothing to overwrite (since it's not a file). Streams can not be overwritten by nature. You just put something in or get something out of a stream.